# Using dot in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following route in RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyLegacyRoute",
    "Content/bootstrap.css",
    new { controller = "Legacy", action = "GetLegacyUrl", legacyUrl = "someUrl" });
```

`~/Content/bootstrap.css` exists and rather than display its content when I navigate to `http://localhost:27541/Content/bootstrap.css`, I want to hit the `GetLegacyUrl` action in the `Legacy` controller.

I have added this to Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" path="/Content/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler" />
...
```

and

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
...
```

However when I access `http://localhost:27541/Content/bootstrap.css` I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Cannot create an abstract class.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.

My controller looks like this:

```
public class LegacyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetLegacyUrl(string legacyUrl)
    {
        return View((object)legacyUrl);
    }
}
```

My view (GetLegacyUrl.cshtml) looks like this:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetLegacyUrl";
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>GetLegacyUrl</h2>
The URL requested was @Model
```

I am trying to do this just so I can learn more about routing.

What can I do to successfully use this route?

Comment: That error seems related to the controller method. What is it? And does it include any parameters which are abstract classes?

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see my updated question.

Comment: Are you actually hitting the controller method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I put a breakpoint in GetLegacyUrl() but it is not getting hit.

Comment: OK. There is something else in the pipeline causing it. And I have just noticed that you are using MVC-5 and `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` should not work with that version. I'll will try and reproduce/debug the source code later today

Comment: Does it have something to do with UrlRoutingHandler being abstract?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171049/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-backwards-dave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by putting this in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

And by making the `preCondition` value an empty string:

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
```

in this file: `C:\Users\user.name\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

I found the answer on pg 99/115 chapter 16 in Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET MVC5 book.

I also removed the handler I added in the Web.config and removed the `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"` since that doesn't work in MVC5.